# Filtering keys in an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two arrays, one called **'arrayGO'** (which stores a list of users coming from the database), and another called **'idtGO'** (which stores a list of user IDs). The **arrayGO** meets the following structure:

> @"Andre-A",@"Aline-A",@"Bruno-B",@"Bola-B",@"Caio-C"

I have a command which can filter this array, separating letters that are after the dash, doing so organize the array:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryIDT = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for (NSString *string in arrayGO) {

        NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
        NSString *key = components[1];
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = dictionary[key];

        if (!tempArray){
            tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        }

        [tempArray addObject:components[0]];
         dictionary[key] = tempArray;
    }
```

This command returns me the array the way I want, which in this case is:

> A =     (
>           Aline,
>           Andre
>       );
>       B =     (
>           Bola,
>           Bruno
>       );
>       C =     (
>           Caio
>       );

However I need to do the same thing with the variable that stores the 'ids' of users, in this cade the array **'idtGO'** meets the following structure:

> @"4",@"1",@"12",@"22",@"33"

All I want to do is the same thing I did with the list of names, so that in this case and ids, I'm trying to get the following result:

> 0 = ( 4, 1 ); 1 = ( 12, 22 ); 2 = ( 33 );

I try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryIDT = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
int idtIndex = 0;
int idtKeys = 0;

for (NSString *string in arrayGO) {

    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

    NSString *key = components[1];
    NSString *keyIdt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", idtIndex];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = dictionary[key];
    NSMutableArray *tempArrayidt = dictionaryIDT[keyIdt];

    if (!tempArray){

        tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        tempArrayidt = [NSMutableArray array];

        [tempArrayidt addObject:keyIdt];
        dictionaryIDT[keyIdt] = tempArrayidt;
        idtKeys++;
        idtIndex++;

    }else{

        idtIndex++;
    }

    [tempArray addObject:components[0]];
    dictionary[key] = tempArray;


}
```

I would be grateful if someone help me to solve this puzzle.

Comment: You would be much better off if you didn't have two separate arrays. Have one array - an array of dictionaries where each dictionary has the name and id. Then you simply organize the array of dictionaries instead of organizing two arrays of strings.

Comment: I haven't got the point between `@"4",@"1",@"12",@"22",@"33"` and `0 = ( 4, 1 ); 1 = ( 12, 22 ); 2 = ( 33 )`. Could you clarify it more?

Comment: Yes! when the command is to create a new key in the variable dictionary, we will also create a new key for dictionaryIDT variable, getting: A = (Aline, Andre); and 0 = (4, 1);, understand now?

Comment: I`m waiting answers to solve my puzzle, you can?

Comment: @rmaddy I pick a code who need to implement in this format, so...I even thought about doing this, but the code I got to work requires me to knife this way I'm trying to do, I think it seems a simple thing there in my code to make it work, so I'm not getting display can help me?

Comment: you can explain the logic behind : 0 = ( 4, 1 ); 1 = ( 12, 22 ); 2 = ( 33 )??? i don't get the organise method, the 4 and 1 (in 0) is the ids of andre-a and aline-a???

Comment: precisely, we assume that the array coming from the database is thus Aline-A, Andre-A,Lucas-L, and his respecitivos ids (ID for the database) is in another array in this way 1,4,2. Similarly when the array is processed and been so A=(Aline, Andre),L=(Lucas) in the same manner array ids will in this case will be 0=(1,4),1=(2),understand now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Guys I try and Try hard and finally get the answer for this puzzle, the code below show how:

```
NSMutableDictionary  *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary  *dictionaryIDT = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
     NSString *keyTemp = @"nulo";

    for (NSString *string in arrayGO) {

        NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

        NSString *key = components[1];

        NSString *keyIdt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", idt[idtKeys]];
        NSString *keyIdtIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",idtIndex];
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = dictionary[key];
        NSMutableArray *tempArrayidt = dictionaryIDT[keyIdtIndex];

        if (!tempArray){

            tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
            tempArrayidt = [NSMutableArray array];

        }

        [tempArray addObject:components[0]];
        dictionary[key] = tempArray;


            if([keyTemp isEqual: @"nulo"]){
                //Veririca se a variavel keyTemp é igual a zero, se ela for isso quer dizer que é a primeira vez que estamos aqui, e se for a variavel keyTemp Sera igual a key

                keyTemp = key;

                [tempArrayidt addObject:keyIdt];
                dictionaryIDT[keyIdtIndex] = tempArrayidt;
                idtKeys++;

            }else{
                //Se caimos aqui entao quer dizer que jaé a segunda vez que nos estamos caindo aqui, neste caso devemos verificar se a keyTemp ainda é a mesma


                if([key isEqual: keyTemp]){
                    //Se for igual é porque nada mudou, ainda estamos tratando aquela chave, entao...

                    [tempArrayidt addObject:keyIdt];
                    dictionaryIDT[keyIdtIndex] = tempArrayidt;
                    idtKeys++;

                }else{

                    //Se nao é porque a key mudou, entao agora nos devemos aumentar o idtIndex, redefinir o idtKeys e falar que a key é igual a keyTemp
                    idtIndex++;

                    keyIdtIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[keyIdtIndex intValue] + 1];

                    idtKeys++;
                    keyTemp = key;

                    //Agora faremos o mesmo esquema de sempre...
                    [tempArrayidt addObject:keyIdt];
                    dictionaryIDT[keyIdtIndex] = tempArrayidt;

                }

            }


    }


NSLog(@"%@",dictionaryIDT);
```